# Callback to $interval function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

How can I make sure the function `runAfterLoopFinishes()` runs after the `$interval` has finished?  Right now it runs immediately after loop is first defined.

```
var loop = $interval(function () {
  // Do something great 10 times
}, 1000, 10);

// To run after looping
runAfterLoopFinishes();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$interval` returns a promise.

```
var loop = $interval(function () {
  // Do something great 10 times
}, 1000, 10);

loop.then(function(){
  // To run after looping
  runAfterLoopFinishes();
}
```

An `$interval` promise will be notified after each iteration, but only resolve after the last.

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna make sure function a run after function b , `async` will help to control it.

```
async.series([
    function(callback){     // function a
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){     // function b
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
function(err, results){
                            // results 
});
```

Comment: AngularJS's `$interval` returns a promise -- using that is much more straightfoward than using the async library which is designed around Node-style callbacks.